# Elastic search river mongodb _meta returning action not found error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I setup elastic search mongodb successfully. I am using Elastic search version 1.3.5 and River version 2.0.2.

When I tried to get the status of river

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta"
```

I got the following error

```
{"success":false,"error":"action not found: /_river/mongodb/_meta"}
```

My river name is "mongodb"

Also I tried _status request

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_status"
{"success":false,"error":"action not found: /_river/mongodb/_status"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, actually the issue was due to the river name **mongodb**. I changed the name to **test_river**. After that `_status`, `_meta`, `_riverstatus` requests worked.

When I used river name **mongodb** I was able to get correct response of all other request like search, status of an index created by river etc.

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_river/test_river/_status"
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "test_river",
  "_id": "_status",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "node": "",
    "id": "pw3UUP7KQcuVSocDLlFdQw",
    "name": "Starshine",
    "transport_address": "inet[/10.3.0.53:9300]"
  }
}

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_river/test_river/_meta"
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "test_river",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
      "db": "test",
      "collection": "employees"
    },
    "index": {
      "name": "el_test",
      "type": "employees"
    }
  }
}

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_river/test_river/_riverstatus
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "test_river",
  "_id": "_riverstatus",
  "_version": 3,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "mongodb": {
      "status": "RUNNING"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the request should use "_status" instead of "_meta":

```
 curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_status"
```

See the [River documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/#status).

Comment: I am getting the same result in this request also. Will update the question with _status request.